# Amazon LEX - Slot type that has more that can accept more than 140 characteres

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-lex

I'm creating a bot to demo and one of the questions is a "tell me about a time where you..." type question. Is there a way that users will be able to respond with *more than* 140 characters?

I'm new to Amazon Lex, thanks in advance!

Thanks,
Niall

Answer (score 0):

The users answers can be longer than 140 characters, the 140 characters limit is in the values of the slots.

Let's take an example, the question is "What is your favorite color?"
When you ask this question, you are trying to fill a slot named "color". 
The values for this slot would be "blue", "red"... Those are the values limited to 140 characters.
Now you can create utterances, that possibly could be longer than 140 characters, for example "My favorite color is {color}" (if you have a very long color name this could be more than 140 characters).

It makes sense that the slots values are limited to 140 characters as you want the user to type exactly the same thing (or one of its synonyms).

You have to think about whether you really need Amazon Lex in that case. 
With a question such as "Tell me about..." , how are you going to list all possible values? What will you do with those values?